# async and await with loops

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a small code written in JavaScript that get the content of html pages then do a process on them (crawler).
the problem is ***request*** causes asynchronous execution.
I tried to use Promises and async & await but still got the same problem asynchronous execution , the reason is i want to crawl multiple pages at once in order to move to the next objective.
Here is a similar code of what i have here :

```
const rootlink= 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/';

async function f (){
    await f1()
    f3()
}

async function f1(){
    return new Promise(async (resolve,reject)=>{
        log('f1 start');
         for(let i=1;i<11;i++){
            await request(rootlink+i,(err, res,html)=>{
                if(!err && res.statusCode==200){
                    log('link '+i +' done');
                    resolve();
                }
                else reject()
            })
        }
    })
}

function f3(){
    console.log('f3')
}

f()
```

the result should be :
f1 start
link 1 done
link 2 done
link 3 done
link 4 done
link 5 done
link 6 done
link 7 done
link 8 done
link 9 done
link 10 done
f3

instead of 
f1 start
link 1 done
f3
link 2 done
link 3 done
link 4 done
link 5 done
link 6 done
link 7 done
link 8 done
link 9 done
link 10 done

Comment: It seems that what you want to achieve is not really asynchronous, you might want to perform a synchronous request instead

Comment: yes that's what i really want

Comment: `return new Promise(async (...` is a bit weird. Why not just `return (async (...) => {...})()`. Probably won't actually change anything, but removing unnecessary code & indentation is never bad for debugging.

Comment: take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NOTE: I would use an isomorphic fetch package like [node-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch) to create code that could be used in multiple environments. Even if you don't plan to use this in a browser, becoming familiar with the API is very beneficial for future use. At very least, this idea allowed me to write a code snippet that you can actually run on StackOverflow.

**[`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) is your answer** no matter what package you use, though. You can simply wait for ALL the promises to resolve, then do your logic:

```js
// const fetch = require('node-fetch')

const fetchData = (...args) => fetch(...args).then(r => {
  if (!r.ok) throw new Error('Error!')
  return r.json()
})

const getAllPostsAsync = (postIds) => Promise.all(
  postIds.map(postId => fetchData(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${postId}`))
)

;(async () => {
  const posts = await getAllPostsAsync([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])
  
  // TODO: Your logic here, after waiting for all posts to load
  console.log(posts)
})()
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that you want to do multiple asychronous operations in parallel, you actually don't want to `await` them, as this would block your function.

First, I would say it's better to find a HTTP library that uses promises. The one you use has callbacks, but I believe the `request` project also has a `request-promise` package that's much easier to use.

Here's a fixed version of your f1 function that uses promises more correctly. Note that this is *not* parallelized yet.

```
const request = require('request-promise');

async function f1(){
  log('f1 start');
  for(let i=1;i<11;i++){
     const res = await request(rootlink+i);
     if(res.statusCode==200){
        log('link '+i +' done');
     }
  }
}
```

Here is another version of this function, except now it's fully parallelized.

```
async function f1(){
  log('f1 start');
  const promises = [];
  for(let i=1;i<11;i++){
     promises.push(
       request(rootlink+i).then( (res) => {
         if(res.statusCode==200){
           log('link '+i +' done');
         }
       })
     );
  }

  await Promise.all(promises);
}
```

This can be made a bit more elegant if this is split up in multiple functions:

```
async function f1(){
  log('f1 start');
  const promises = [];
  for(let i=1;i<11;i++){
     promises.push(checkLink(i));
  }

  await Promise.all(promises);
}

async function checkLink(i) {
  const res = await request(rootlink+i);
  if (res.statusCode==200){
     log('link '+i +' done');
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Sir for the answer

Comment: The problem is in my case i have to do it in a synchronous operations in order to store results later in a file. reality my second function (f2) crawl according to result given by the first function (f1). then there is another function that store results when the 2 previews functions finish doing they job.

Answer (score 0):

The answer of my question is to use an synchronous request 'sync-request' from 
 https://www.npmjs.com/package/sync-request

Comment: This package warns "you should not be using this in a production application". I would advise against settling with `sync-request` as your solution

Comment: Yes i saw that warning. Its my only solution for the moment till i figure out a better solution ( i ll think of another way to do this job with avoiding synchronous operations)